# Convert JSON Object to C# Object

Tags: c#, json

I have a json object and I am trying to convert it to my c# object. Here is my JSON:

```
{"GuvenlikNoktaArray": {"GuvenlikNoktası": [{"Id": 1,"GuvenlikNoktası1":"SANTIYE","KartNo":"000001889174217","Sira": 1},{"Id": 2,"GuvenlikNoktası1":"INSAAT","KartNo":"000000803567858","Sira": 2},{"Id": 3,"GuvenlikNoktası1":"ÇALISMA","KartNo":"000003417926233","Sira": 3},{"Id": 4,"GuvenlikNoktası1":"GÜVENLIK","KartNo":"000001888909897","Sira": 4}]}}
```

And my c# class:

```
 public partial class GuvenlikNoktası
{
    public GuvenlikNoktası()
    {
        this.GüvenlikNoktasıOlay = new HashSet<GüvenlikNoktasıOlay>();
        this.PanikButonuAlarmlari = new HashSet<PanikButonuAlarmlari>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GuvenlikNoktası1 { get; set; }
    public string KartNo { get; set; }
    public string Sira { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GüvenlikNoktasıOlay> GüvenlikNoktasıOlay { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PanikButonuAlarmlari> PanikButonuAlarmlari { get; set; }
}
```

And last, my convert try:

```
public void AddIstasyon(string json_string)
{
    GuvenlikNoktası result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GuvenlikNoktası>(json_string);
}
```

I don't get any errors but when I debuged, I see that all attributes inside 'result' are null. It seems like an empty object. How can I get a correct 'GuvenlikNoktası' object ? (Btw I am pretty sure I am getting the json object correctly).

Comment: First of all, your `Sira` property is defined as a string when in the JSON array, it is an integer.

Comment: More guide to use json with C#: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Secondly, when you're deserializing, it seems you're deserializing your JSON into a single instance of your `GuvenlikNoktası` class, when the JSON itself is an array of said class.

Comment: Your JSON and Class structure does not matchs. Also using Newtonsoft.Json gives much more performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must keep this JSON structure as-is you may use JObject to navigate inside your JSON properties until you reach your target objects to deserizlize. Please can you try the code below;

**PS: This code uses Newtonsoft.Json;**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SO_39847703
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"GuvenlikNoktaArray\": {\"GuvenlikNoktası\": [{\"Id\": 1,\"GuvenlikNoktası1\":\"SANTIYE\",\"KartNo\":\"000001889174217\",\"Sira\": 1},{\"Id\": 2,\"GuvenlikNoktası1\":\"INSAAT\",\"KartNo\":\"000000803567858\",\"Sira\": 2},{\"Id\": 3,\"GuvenlikNoktası1\":\"ÇALISMA\",\"KartNo\":\"000003417926233\",\"Sira\": 3},{\"Id\": 4,\"GuvenlikNoktası1\":\"GÜVENLIK\",\"KartNo\":\"000001888909897\",\"Sira\": 4}]}}";
            AddIstasyon(json);
        }

        public static void AddIstasyon(string json_string)
        {
            dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json_string);
            string jsonToDeserializeStrongType = jsonObject["GuvenlikNoktaArray"]["GuvenlikNoktası"].ToString();
            List<GuvenlikNoktası> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GuvenlikNoktası>>(jsonToDeserializeStrongType); ;
        }
    }

    public partial class GuvenlikNoktası
    {
        public GuvenlikNoktası()
        {
            this.GüvenlikNoktasıOlay = new HashSet<GüvenlikNoktasıOlay>();
            this.PanikButonuAlarmlari = new HashSet<PanikButonuAlarmlari>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string GuvenlikNoktası1 { get; set; }
        public string KartNo { get; set; }
        public string Sira { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GüvenlikNoktasıOlay> GüvenlikNoktasıOlay { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PanikButonuAlarmlari> PanikButonuAlarmlari { get; set; }
    }

    public class GüvenlikNoktasıOlay
    {

    }

    public class PanikButonuAlarmlari
    {

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data and your class definition do not fit together. Therefore the default values (NULL) are provided by the serializer.

In order to deserialize the given JSON data you need a class structure like:

```
public class Root
{
     public LevelOne GuvenlikNoktaArray {get; set;}
}

public class LevelOne {
    public IEnumerable<GuvenlikNoktası> GuvenlikNoktası {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, rboe is correct. Use this `https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/`  to see how the structure looks, and then use this `http://json2csharp.com/` so see the structure it needs to be parsed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class.

```
public class GuvenlikNoktası
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GuvenlikNoktası1 { get; set; }
    public string KartNo { get; set; }
    public int Sira { get; set; }
}

public class GuvenlikNoktaArray
{
    public IList<GuvenlikNoktası> GuvenlikNoktası { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public GuvenlikNoktaArray GuvenlikNoktaArray { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this link For your referencehttp://jsonutils.com/.